# Got an error while adding the soapui-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, soapui

Got an error while adding the `soapui-maven-plugin` to the POM Entry:

> Error: Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-pro-maven-plugin:5.1.2 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved

**Analysis:**
Issue occurred while adding test in POM.XML

Issue occurred while adding below `phase` element in POM.XML'

```xml
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    <phase>test</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Issue occurred while adding <phase>test</phase> in POM.XML<executions>
     <execution>      
      <goals>
       <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>test</phase>
     </execution>
    </executions>

Comment: Show the rest of your pom, otherwise: cannot reproduce!

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert id:

```
<executions>
    <execution>
      <id>soapUI</id> 
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
```